# Standard Deviation of Averaging filter

Tags: standard-deviation, image-processing

I am wondering why the standard deviation of the averaging filter of width w is as follows? Where does the 12 in the denominator come from? For context, the paper is am refererring to can be found here:  [here](https://web.csse.uwa.edu.au/research/?a=826172)

[image]

Comment: Hi! Please take the time to add all the relevant information to your question in the post.

Comment: This is a post about using several passes of the average filter to approximate a gaussian filter. The premise starts with the expression above which I am not sure how it was derived?

Comment: The paper is awful insofar as it never clearly states what it is doing.  All that's going on here is that the author is reporting the standard deviation of the uniform distribution on the set $\{1,2,\ldots, w\}.$ One way to *see* where $1/12$ comes from is to compute the variance of the continuous uniform distribution on the interval $[0,1],$ equal to $$\int_0^1(x-1/2)^2\,\mathrm dx=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}x^2\,\mathrm dx=\frac{x^3}{3}\bigg|^{1/2}_{-1/2}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^3\right)=\frac{1}{12}.$$

Comment: @whuber - That makes sense. Thank you.